# Creating token blocks to hold environment contents and printing from them later

Tags: environments, e-tex

I have the following, works well for one toks block i.e \savedenvtoks but i want to create more toks blocks and i want the \savedenv to take a parameter indicating whichs toks block to add to, and i want the \printallsaved command to take a parameter indicating which tok block to print from.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex,environ,refcount}

\globtoksblk\savedenvtoks{1000}
\newcounter{savedenvcount}

\NewEnviron{savedenv}[1][]{%
 \refstepcounter{savedenvcount}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
   \label{#1}%
  \fi
  \global\toks\numexpr\savedenvtoks+\value{savedenvcount}\relax=\expandafter{\BODY}%
}
\toks\savedenvtoks={??}

\newcommand{\printsaved}[1]{%
  \the\toks\numexpr\savedenvtoks+\getrefnumber{#1}\relax
 }

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\printallsaved}{%
 \@tempcnta=\z@
 \loop
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<\value{savedenvcount}
  \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \the\toks\numexpr\savedenvtoks+\@tempcnta\relax\par
  \repeat
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{savedenv}
  Something for a
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}
 Something for b
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}
Something with no label
\end{savedenv}

\textbf{Print all of them}

\printallsaved

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can abstract the ideas in the previous answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex,environ,refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\declaresaveclass}[2][1000]{%
 \expandafter\globtoksblk\csname ncory@class@#2\endcsname{#1}%
 \global\expandafter\toks\csname ncory@class@#2\endcsname{??}%
 \newcounter{ncory@class@count@#2}%
 \@namedef{thencory@class@count@#2}{%
   \number\csname ncory@class@#2\endcsname+\arabic{ncory@class@count@#2}\relax
 }%
}

\NewEnviron{savedenv}[2][]{%
 \refstepcounter{ncory@class@count@#2}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
   \label{#1}%
  \fi
  \global\toks\ncory@compute@v{#2}=\expandafter{\BODY}%
}

\newcommand\ncory@compute@v[1]{%
  \numexpr\csname ncory@class@#1\endcsname+\value{ncory@class@count@#1}\relax
}
\newcommand\ncory@compute@r[2]{%
  \numexpr\csname ncory@class@#2\endcsname+\getrefnumber{#1}\relax
}

\newcommand{\printsaved}[2]{%
  \toks0={??}%
  \the\toks\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1}\relax\par
 }

\newcommand{\printallsaved}[1]{%
 \@tempcnta=\z@
 \loop
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<\value{ncory@class@count@#1}
  \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \the\toks\numexpr\csname ncory@class@#1\endcsname+\@tempcnta\relax\par
  \repeat
 }
\makeatother

\declaresaveclass{ONE}
\declaresaveclass[500]{TWO} % less registers for this class

\begin{document}

\begin{savedenv}[a]{ONE}
  Something for a/ONE
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}[b]{TWO}
 Something for b/TWO
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}{ONE}
Something with no label
\end{savedenv}

\textbf{Print all of them}

\textbf{ONE:}

\printallsaved{ONE}

\textbf{TWO:}

\printallsaved{TWO}

\textbf{Print by name}

\printsaved{a}

\printsaved{b}

\end{document}
```

You declare a new save class, optionally adjusting the number of reserved registers. Then you can either print all the registers in a class or still print any of them by name. Printing by name requires two LaTeX runs (if labels are changed), since it uses the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image: picture]

We could add error checking if the range of allowed registers for a class is overflown, but reserving 1000 of them should already be quite safe.